# Is Ruby on Rails with Draper or Apotomo a MVVM?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, mvvm, decorator, single-page-application

Some facts/assumptions:

1. It is said that Ruby on Rails follows MVC architectural pattern.
2. The MVVM (Model View ViewModel), which derives from MVC, offers an abstraction layer, where all the buttons, labels and links (View) are separated from the way models expose data (ViewModel).
3. Some Javascript frameworks, that excel in building Single Page Apps, leverage MVVM pattern (for instance Knockout.js).
4. If we check [Ruby toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_presenters), we will see a several presenter solutions like Draper and Apotomo that work just as a ViewModel thing.

Assuming there is no bs in my 'facts' section, there is one thing that bothers me:

- Can we call Rails with Draper, Apotomo (or other presenter/decorator) a MVVM solution?
- Can we say we are following MVVM pattern with Rails, if we encapsulate the data from the model in a form of decorator/presenter container with Draper?
- Or is there something missing and we can't call it a MVVM, like Knockout.js?

Thank you for your insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in my opinion.... I think of MVVM as creating specific view objects that are disconnected from the underlying data/domain object.

With the Rails presenter pattern, these presenters will typically wrap around the active record object and add methods to it that pertain to the presentation.

Comment: Presenter/decorator being thightly coupled with a Model layer is for sure the case with Draper - I agree. But what about Apotomo? Imagine, you're using Apotomo for rendering charts (let's say higcharts.com). You code it so apotomo widget takes as a param series of data (just labels and numbers) and diplays it in a predefined way. Do approach like this meets your expectations about "disconnection from the model layer"? Thank you for your answers and opinions, I appreciate that!

Comment: @socjopata Well, I think if you were to create a view object and send it to apotomo, then sure... but I don't think apotomo would require this disconnection.

Comment: I was kinda hoping for some more discussion with other stackoverflow users on this matter. Nevertheless, "the green tick" belongs to you. Thank you for your opinions :)

Comment: @socjopata I agree with you, I was hoping to see more discussions here on SO... I recently applied MVVM on one of my iOS apps (that works with a Rails JSON backend) and it was great. Now I'm building a somewhat heavy HTML/CSS Rails app and am wondering if I can apply same MVVM approach with it. If you think about it MVVM in the nutshell is just a way to structure your code - you don't have to use Apotomo or Draper, you can just create your own POROs to be ViewModels and get the data from them to render in your views.

Comment: But than again there is an entire infrastructure in Rails to directly hook ViewHelpers to ActiveModels....